# C# Get all keys from a list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I basically want to know how to write this ([Extract all keys from a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399384/extract-all-keys-from-a-list-of-dictionaries)) in C#.

I have a list of dictionaries which have all unique keys.

I want to extract all of them into a list of string (as the key is string).

```
private List<Dictionary<string, string>> dictList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
     new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "a", "b" } },
     new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "c", "d" } },
};

private void GetDictListKeys()
{
    List<string> keyList = new List<string>();
    foreach(var dict in dictList)
    {
        keyList.Add(dict.Keys.ToString());
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to flatten your enumerable of keys and dump it into a collection (`HashSet` used cause you mentioned duplicates, and because that's also what your linked answer used in Python):

```
var allKeys = dictList.SelectMany(d => d.Keys).ToHashSet();
```

Comment: If you actually want a list, use `ToList()` instead.

Comment: ... or if you want unique keys but a list use `dictList.SelectMany(d => d.Keys).Distinct().ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

You can create another foreach loop inside yours:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string,string> dict in dictList)
{
    foreach(string key in dict.Keys)
    {
        keyList.Add(key);                 
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't really think of having two loops! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use AddRange.

```
    foreach (var dict in dictList)
    {
        keyList.AddRange(dict.Keys);
    }
```

Comment: Another beautiful way to get what I wanted. Thank you!